# Java Apache POI - Cell Formatting Stops and Restarts Working

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a program that takes an input file and puts it into excel. Everything works great until around the 32000th line. Suddenly the left alignment formatting stops working. Additionally, it seems to suddenly restart working around the 65000th row. I am not sure what is happening or why. I have supplied the code for the function that the formatting occurs.

```
private static void addDataToExcel(ArrayList<String[]> rowList, int amtOfColumns){
    SXSSFRow row = null;
    String[] colValues = null;

    for(int i = 1 ; i<= rowList.size() ;i++){
        row = (SXSSFRow) worksheet.createRow(rowCount);
        //TODO: Check if really necessary since for loop starts at 1 now
        if(i == 0){

        } else {
            colValues = rowList.get(i-1);
        }
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

        for(int j=0; j < amtOfColumns; j++){    
            if(colValues[j] == null){
                SXSSFCell cell = (SXSSFCell) row.createCell(j);

                cell.setCellValue(colValues[j+1]);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
            }

            else{
                //System.out.println(j);
                SXSSFCell cell = (SXSSFCell) row.createCell(j);

                cell.setCellValue(colValues[j]);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
            }
        }   
        rowCount++;
    }

    System.out.println("Running...");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating one cell style per row, which isn't how you should do things. Excel has a fairly low limit on the maximum number of cell styles that a workbook can handle.

Since Cell Styles are workbook scoped, you should change your code to instead be

```
SXSSFRow row = null;
String[] colValues = null;

CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setAlignment(XSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_RIGHT);

for (int i = 1 ; i<= rowList.size() ; i++) {
    row = (SXSSFRow) worksheet.createRow(rowCount);
```

That will prevent you from running out of available cell styles, and so should allow your program to work correctly

Comment: Thank you for your response. This fixed my issue